# Правильно построить запрос к БД. SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Исходные данные:

```
CREATE TABLE ed_words (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    eng varchar(20),
    rus varchar(20),
    owner int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES ed_users(id)
);
```

Таблица содержит колонку со словом на английском и колонку со словом на русском. Например у нас есть такие данные:

```
INSERT INTO `ed_words` (eng,rus,owner) VALUES ('word1','перевод1',1),('word2','перевод2',1),('word3','перевод3',1);
```

Например я хочу добавить слово word1 но с другим переводом как-то так:

```
INSERT INTO `ed_words` (eng,rus,owner) VALUES ('word1','перевод4',1);
```

Вставлять нужно сразу по нескольку слов в запросе, от одного до inf, некоторые слова могут уже быть в БД, некоторых может не быть. Мне нужно, чтобы если слово уже существует перезаписался только перевод, т.е. чтобы не было дубликатов английских слов. Возможно ли это сделать как-то с помощью триггеров, либо как можно решить этот вопрос. Работаю на PHP, субд MySQL.

Comment: Для вашей задачи подошел бы оператор MERGE, но MySQL его не поддерживает. Я думаю, что придется писать два оператора - один удалит имеющиеся слова из списка, а второй их добавит.

Comment: Связка DELETE, INSERT работает, получается 2 запроса. Хотелось бы в один запрос все поместить для чувства удовлетворения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужна функция [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

`INSERT INTO ed_words (eng,rus,owner) VALUES ('word1','перевод1',1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rus='перевод1';`

MULIPLES

`INSERT INTO ed_words (eng,rus,owner)
    VALUES
    ('word1','перевод1',1),
    ('word2','перевод2',1),
    ('word3','перевод3',1),
    ('word4','перевод4',1),
    ('word5','перевод5',1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    rus=VALUES(rus), 
    owner=VALUES(owner)`

Comment: Супер, спасибо, работает, если на eng поставить UNIQUE. Тут все понятно, когда у нас добавляется одна строка, а возможно ли добавить сразу несколько строк с заменой?
т.е. что то типа такого: `INSERT INTO ed_words (eng,rus,owner) VALUES ('word1','перевод1',1),('word2','перевод2',1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rus='перевод1','перевод2';`?

Comment: Добавил мульти вставку, проверил должно работать. `owner` добавляйте если меняется владелец записи.

Comment: ну идобавить еще вот так  **ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci**

Comment: Спасибо, работает, т.е. VALUES(Значение) берет значение которое мы передаем в конкретной каждой строке?

Comment: Да. Псевдо переменная.